# COM and Multithreading in Pascal/Delphi, CoUninitialize does not return

Tags: multithreading, delphi, com, activex, freepascal

I am using the following (pseudo)code in Free Pascal to allow access to a COM object in multithreaded applications:

```
type
  TCoObjectInstance = record
    ThreadID: TThreadID;
    CoObject: TLB.CoObject;
  end;

type
  TCoObjectWrapper = class(...)
  strict private
    FCoObjectInstance: array[0..9] of TCoObjectInstance;
  public
    constructor Create; override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure InitializeThread;
    procedure LeaveThread;
    function CoInstance: MyCoInstance;
    procedure UseCoInstance;
    //...
  end;

var
  MyOneCoObjectWrapper: TOneCoObjectWrapper;

type
  TDoSomethingThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    Finished: boolean;
    // ...
  end;


// TDoSomethingThread

procedure TDoSomethingThread.Execute;
begin
    MyOneCoObjectWrapper.InitializeThread;
    while (not Terminated) do
    begin
        MyOneCoObjectWrapper.UseCoInstance;
        Sleep(100);
    end;
    MyOneCoObjectWrapper.LeaveThread; // <--------------- !!!
  end;
  Finished := True;
end;


// TCoObjectWrapper

constructor TCoObjectWrapper.Create;
begin
   // ...
  OleCheck(CoInitializeEx(nil, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED));
  FCoObjectInstances[0].ThreadID := GetThreadID;
  FCoObjectInstances[0].CoObject := CoObject.Create;
  GIT.RegisterInterfaceInGlobal(FCoObjectInstances[0].CoObject, TLB.CoObject, CoInterfaceMarshalCookie);
  // ...
end;

destructor TCoObjectWrapper.Destroy;
begin
   // ...
  CoUninitialize;
  // ...
end;

procedure TCoObjectWrapper.InitializeThread;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  OleCheck(CoInitializeEx(nil, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED));

  // Find next free instance
  i := Low(FCoObjectInstances) + 1;
  while Assigned(FCoObjectInstances[i].CoObject) and (i <= High(FCoObjectInstances)) do
    Inc(i);
  if (i > High(FCoObjectInstances)) then
    raise Exception.Create('Ran out of instances in InitializeThread!');

  GIT.GetInterfaceFromGlobal(CoInterfaceMarshalCookie, TLB.CoObject, FCoObjectInstances[i].CoObject);
  FCoObjectInstances[i].ThreadID := GetThreadID;
end;

procedure TCoObjectWrapper.LeaveThread;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  i := Low(FCoObjectInstances) + 1;
  while (FCoObjectInstances[i].ThreadID <> GetThreadID) and (i <= High(FCoObjectInstances)) do
    Inc(i);
  if (i > High(FCoObjectInstances)) then
    raise ELogged.Create('Instance not found');
  FCoObjectInstances[i].ThreadID := 0;
  FCoObjectInstances[i].CoObject := nil;
  CoUninitialize; // <----- !
end;

function TCoObjectWrapper.CoInstance: TLB.CoObject;
var
  i: integer = Low(FCoObjectInstances);
begin
  Result := nil;
  while (not Assigned(Result)) and (i <= High(FCoObjectInstances)) do
  begin
    if (FCoObjectInstances[i].ThreadID = GetThreadID) then
      Result := FCoObjectInstances[i].CoObject;
    Inc(i);
  end;
  if not Assigned(Result) then
    raise Exception.Create('Instance not found');
end;

procedure TCoObjectWrapper.UseCoInstance;
begin
   // Do somthing with the COM object
end;
```

This is supposed to work as follows:

- In FormCreate (main thread), a global instance of TCoObjectWrapper (MyOneCoObjectWrapper) 
  is created
- Methods of MyOneCoObjectWrapper are called from the main thread, accessing the encapsulated COM object
- From the main thread, an instance of TDoSomethingThread is created. Once the thread is started, it initializes it's COM via calling MyOneCoObjectWrapper.IntitializeThread
- The main thread and the subthread access the COM object
- Upon Termination of the thread, MyOneCoObjectWrapper.LeaveThread is called to finalize COM for this thread (THIS IS WHERE THINGS GET STUCK - see below)
- Some more use of the COM object by the main thread
- In FormDestroy (main thread), the global instance of TCoObjectWrapper is destroyed and COM for the main thread is finalized in TCoObjectWrapper.Destroy

My questions are:

- Code-wise, is this a completely dumb way to approach this problem?
- It works very well, both from the main thread as well as from the subthreads. The only problem is that very often, TCoObjectWrapper.LeaveThread hangs at CoUninitialize and the program freezes. Is there any explanation for this behaviour, how can I analyse that further?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want `COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED`

Comment: Your `TCoObjectWrapper.Create` is calling `CoInitializeEx` itself, why?  Your `TCoObjectWrapper.LeaveThread` is clearing the entry, but it's not `Release`ing the interface pointer it got from the GIT.  Where does `Terminated` come from?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The corresponding CLSID entry in the registry told me a ThreadingModel of "Apartment" - is that wrong? (Documentation on that COM interface is pretty poor.)

Comment: @PauloMadeira: CoObjectWrapper.Create is calling CoInitializeEx itself, because it also creates one instance of the COM object. Releasing the interface pointer of the GIT - how do you do that? And Terminated is set at some point in TCoObjectWrapper, sorry, forgot that piece of code!

Comment: As for `TCoObjectWrapper.Create`, it shouldn't call `CoInitializeEx` itself, it's one way how `CoInitializeEx` shouldn't be called, i.e. from a library call in some existing thread.  Worse is `MyOneCoObjectWrapper` is initialized in the first thread, so you're effectively forcing it to be in the STA implicitly instead of explicitly.  As for the GIT, you get an interface pointer in `TCoObjectWrapper.InitializeThread` that you never `Release`, but you should.

Comment: Finally, one reason why `CoUninitialize` is not returning is that the code that sets `Terminated` to true is also destroying `MyOneCoObjectWrapper`, which calls `CoUninitialize` (again implicitly) and in turn it makes the COM object become invalid, because its containing apartment is gone.

Comment: I suggest that you simplify the code so that we can get a handle on what's going on.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's difficult for me to simplify the code, because at this point I am not sure what parts could be relevant. I have, however, added a description above of what (I think) is going on - I hope that helps to understand. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I can't do any more without any simplification. It might be difficult for you to do it, but it's your code. Imagine what it's like for us.  Never mind. Somebody else might be able to help.

Comment: @PauloMadeira, instead of calling CoInitializeEx from TCoObjectWrapper.Create, where am I supposed to call (and finalize) it? Does InitializeThread make more sense to you with the additional information I added in the original posting (how code is supposed to flow)?

Comment: `CoInitializeEx` should be called in your program's main block, either explicitly or through some function which will expressly call it.  In light of your edit, I think you're doing it well, I was thinking the singleton was being initialized in a unit, which would run even before the main program's block.  `CoInitializeEx` should also be called in threads you create when you want to use COM, and this you're doing right too.  Also, Delphi does automatic `AddRef` and `Release`, so most of what I commented was my ignorance.

Comment: Try switching the type of field `CoObject: TLB.CoObject` to the default interface that `TLB.CoObject` implements, it seems Delphi will automatically `AddRef` when assigning with casting (actualy `QueryInterface`ing), but not as you currently have.  It can even be `IUnknown`.